# Where is getActivity() on Android Wear Face?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-studio, wear-os, watch-face-api

I am inside of AnalogWatchFaceService class, which is a sample Android Wear Face provided in Android Studio. I imported an API for doing something interesting and I need to pass getActivity() as a parameter for an object. 
http://www.hamweather.com/support/documentation/mobile/android/loading/ 
shows what I am trying to do exactly. Anyway it does not recognize getActivity() when I call it. I'm not really sure about what I'm looking for and neither do I know what an activity really is. Please help and thanks!

Comment: all it is looking for is context, you dont need specifically `getActivity()`

Comment: This is a basic question and I know a little bit about using the Receiver for example where I use Context..... How would I use Context here exactly?

Comment: I have no idea where "here" is

Comment: When I place Context in the parameter, will the function work the same way? I mean what do contexts really do, and how are they retrieved? I think that question might get me somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the example calls `getActivity()` to use the `Activity` as a `Context` (which is a base class for `Activity`). `WatchFaceService` is a subclass of `Context`, so anywhere you would pass the result of `getActivity()`, you can also pass `this` (or if you are inside the Engine, you will pass `AnalogWatchFaceService.this`).